# Segfault in gtkmm implementation of conway's game of life

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gtkmm, conways-game-of-life

As mentioned in the question, I have a segfault in the implementation of Conway's game of life in gtkmm that I am working on.

It can be found here: https://github.com/sakekasi/game-of-life

The backtrace of the error can be found here: https://gist.github.com/3505525

When I insert print statements in cells_get or create_updated grid, it starts printing, doesn't produce a segfault and goes on forever without doing anything.

Comment: Have you built debug mode and run under a debugger?

Comment: yes. the problem with gtk apps is that when I run the application at the end of my main file, I can't debug very well as the actual app is in another thread.

Comment: use breakpoints to focus on the problem methods.

Comment: If you're using gdb, then the technique is as follows. When the program halts (whether due to segfault or breakpoint), `info threads` gives you a list of running threads and where they were interrupted. If it's not immediately apparent which one is your app, then you can flip through them with `thread 1`, `thread 2`, etc. and get a `backtrace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create_updated_grid` is accessing cells off the edge of the grid.  It's calling things like `cells_get(i+1,j)`.

You need to change your out-of-bounds checks in `cells_get` to `>=`, not `>`.

Comment: stupid mistake on my part. That did the trick. thanks!